# MySQL IN clause is too slow, cannot get JOIN to work properly

Tags: mysql, join, search, sql-like, multiple-tables

I have a little problem that I cannot wrap my head around.

This query does exactly what I need, only it takes forever and just kills mysql daemon.

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM inventory 
 WHERE 
    mac LIKE '%".$s."%' 
    OR uid IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE username LIKE '%".$s."%')"
```

The proper way is to go with JOIN clause but unfortunately I cannot get it to work.

Basically, I'm trying to search two tables and then choose records either based on mac-address or username.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also "%anything" is a performance killer

Comment: @Strawberry: ... as well as `OR`

Comment: Can you not search on other columns? Sometimes I create extra artificial  columns to aid searching.

Comment: what does your `JOIN` attempt look like? Also why wouldn't you know the distinct username or mac address you're looking for?

Comment: @PreetSangha indexes will do nothing as long as `LIKE %` is being used.

Comment: @Cfreak, it's a filtering thing for jtables. onkeyup() gets the new list data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
"SELECT i.*
   FROM inventory i
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT c.id
            FROM clients c
           WHERE c.username LIKE '%".$s."%'
           GROUP BY c.id
        ) v
     ON v.id = i.uid
  WHERE i.mac LIKE '%".$s."%'
     OR v.id IS NOT NULL"
```

This should be significantly more efficient than re-executing the IN (subquery) for each and every row in the inventory table. But the query is still problematic, in that it has to perform a full scan of every row in both the `inventory` and `clients` tables.

Comment: This works great! Unfortunately I cannot upvote yet... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT inventory.* 
 FROM inventory LEFT JOIN clients ON (inventory.uid=clients.id)
 WHERE 
    mac LIKE '%".$s."%' OR username LIKE '%".$s."%'
```

Comment: Just a couple of notes; in the OP query, it's returning columns only from `inventory`; this query returns columns from both `inventory` and the `clients` tables. Also, if there is more than one row in `clients`  which matches `inventory.uid`, this will return "duplicate" rows from `inventory. (The OP query doesn't do that.) Adding a GROUP BY on the primary key (or other set of unique, non-null columns) will eliminate the generated duplicates.

Comment: `uid` is a foreign key to the `clients` table's primary key `id`. As a primary key it would be unique by definition, so there is no problem.

Comment: I entirely missed that the `id` column was defined as the primary key of `inventory`.